# how to get street coordinate from google map api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, web-applications

I am trying to make a web app based on google map api.I want to put image icon at different position of street in map.
how wiil i get these street coordinate from google map api?
Please give your useful suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "street coordinate"?

Comment: I mean coordinate of latitude and longitude of streets.

Comment: i have written a html code which display google map.I have put image icon 'images.png'  at particular position of map.Now i want to put these image icon at different coordinates of street in map. is any way to get these street coordinates?

Comment: A street is not a single point, so are you after a specific lat/long pair for the street, or the path that describes the street? Did you just want the lat/long from where the end user clicks/taps?

Answer (score 1):

Google have a service called Geocoding - you send a request including an address, a `google.maps.latLng`, or a Place_ID and it returns an array with all three of them. they explain all about this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Comment: Geocoding will return locations with "ROOFTOP" accuracy if possible.  Those won't be "on the street".